# Showing logo from json to listview

Tags: java, arrays, json

I want to show logo from json but it doesn't work. Check my code and inform  me about the bug. Else app name and description working fine. They only problem is that it now showing logo. Json is passing the link of that logo. I also use Glide but it doesn't work for me. I done all thing to fix it but i am unable for fix it. All code related to this is below. Please have a look at it

```html
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class BrandshaperActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_brandshaper);
        new ParseTask().execute();
    }
    private class ParseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String resultJson = "";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                String $url_json = "https://myapi.ga";
                URL url = new URL($url_json);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                resultJson = buffer.toString();
                Log.d("FOR_LOG", resultJson);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return resultJson;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
            super.onPostExecute(strJson);

            final ListView lView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);

            String[] from = {"app_name","desc","app_logo"};
            int[] to = {R.id.app_name,R.id.desc,R.id.app_logo};

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> hashmap;

            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(strJson);
                JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("offers");

                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject friend = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String appname = friend.getString("name");

                    String description = friend.getString("description");

                    String applogo = friend.getString("icon");

                    Picasso.get().load(arrayList.get(position).getThumbnailUrl(applogo)).into(app);

                    hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hashmap.put("app_name", "" + appname);
                    hashmap.put("desc", "" + description);
                    arrayList.add(hashmap);
                }

                final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(BrandshaperActivity.this, arrayList, R.layout.brandshaper_item,from , to);
                lView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:gravity="left">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">




        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="12dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/app_logo"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:paddingStart="3dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/img_bigcash">
                </ImageView>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/app_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/avenirblack"
                        android:text="BigCash"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/desc"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_regular"
                        android:text="Install &amp; Sign up to 200 coins"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="12dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="end">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/arrow"></ImageView>


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>
```

```html
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvMain"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```